# Symfony2: long running script returns internal server error

Tags: php, symfony, apache2

I'm making a Web service with Symfony2 that do a long running task, this task is about to add a huge data to database.

I testing this web service with PostMan
It took about 5 minutes and it returns "500 Internal Server Error" without any error explanation and without finishing the process.

By the way, I made the same process in a Symfony console command and it took about 3 minutes without any problem.

I configured the php.ini

```
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 5000
```

So I'm thinking that the problem is coming from apache2 ?

Here is the response header took with PostMan:

```
Connection → close
Content-Length → 0
Content-Type → text/html
Date → Mon, 25 Jan 2016 16:34:26 GMT
Server → Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Vary → Authorization
X-Powered-By →
X-Powered-By
Specifies the technology (ASP.NET, PHP, JBoss, e.g.) supporting the web application (version details are often in X-Runtime, X-Version, or X-AspNet-Version)
PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
```

Comment: Check max_execution_time and memory_limit in php.ini?

Comment: I set the max_execution_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1024M

Comment: can be that the client's connection times out? try to add a `ignore_user_abort(true);`

Comment: check apache logs to find out the reason of 500

Comment: The error might be from apache if it is set up to use php-fpm - it waits for output from your script and doesn't get it in time. You can try to output white characters at  regular interval: `echo "      \n";`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem!
What I'm doing is inserting about 200k of rows in database table which is huge, and symfony is loggin all the queries in the log file.

I disabled the doctrine2 sql logger:

```
$dbConnection->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

Everything went alright now.

**PS:** For those who got problems with bulk insert in the database with doctrine, never use the regular entity manager to persist data with Entity objects, better get the PDO connect and insert with a key => value array of the data and make a transaction for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch processing in addition.
Here an example :

```
<?php
$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
    $user = new CmsUser;
    $user->setStatus('user');
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i);
    $user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);
    $em->persist($user);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
}
$em->flush(); // Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
$em->clear();
```

Regards,